# Can I automatically remove my signature from all replies? Mail 6.2 OS x 10.8.2

Tags: macos, mail.app

In OS X Mail.app (version 6.2 from OS X 10.8.2), I can see how to automatically add a signature for all **new** messages, but I do not want it automatically added when I **reply** to a message. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about Mac Mail, iOS, ... ?

Comment: Yes, Mac Mail(6.2) OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! To help others help you, please provide as many details as necessary to precisely define the scope of your question – in this case, the OS and version at the very least belong in the question (you can and should edit your question – do not add essential content in the comments). You might also want to take a peek at the [faq] to get more familiar with the workings of this site.

Comment: I have set up my signature and it appears at the bottom of every new message I write. When I reply to a message my signature automatically appears above their text and the only way I can remove it is by manually clicking on the signature box on the right. What I ideally want is a rule similar to Outlook - dont apply signature to replies - instead of having it always turned on and having to manually remove it from every reply.

Comment: I got that (I edited your question to reflect that), but that is exactly the kind of context that belongs into the question proper. Editing your question is proper behaviour around here :).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone ever answered this. I came here looking for a solution which was ever so simple.

Open Mail.app, go to Mail -> Preferences or use the key-combo <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>

Select the Tab that says 'Signatures' and uncheck the box that says to have the 'signature' above quoted text.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, this is a helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not believe this is possible in Mac Mail. I have been seeking a similar solution for a while, and I've yet to discover one.

There are ways you can make it a little easier to manually add and remove the signatures you want. For example, you can set your default signature to None, but then manually add your signature for all new emails. This preference is controlled under Mail > Preferences > Signatures. (To access this preference, you must select a mail account that the signature preference will be applied to in the leftmost pane. The box will not be clickable if All Signatures is chosen in the left pane.)

[image: image showing location of the Choose Signature preference in Mac Mail, located under Mail > Preferences > Signatures]

For me, this works acceptably - I reply to many more emails threads than I send new emails - but it may be different for your workflow.

Turning off `Place signature above quoted text` directly below the default signature selection box may also help. It doesn't remove the signature from the email entirely - instead, it separates the signature from the main body of your reply and appends it to the end of the email, after all quoted material. This will lead to many signatures all ganged up at the bottom of an email - one for each of your replies.

[image: location of the Place signature above quoted text preference in Mac Mail, found in Mail > Preferences > Signatures]

While the signature is still included in the message, choosing to place the signature after the quoted text may achieve the effect you are hoping for, as many email recipients will read all the way to the bottom of the quoted text in each reply to see the signature. It does not remove it entirely, however.

As you know, Outlook 2011 offers this feature on the Mac. I have heard that Mozilla Thunderbird supplies this functionality as well, but I cannot confirm that myself.